# what is [X,Y] in the Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff formula?

Tags: exponential-function, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I'm looking at the wikipedia article on the [Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula).  It is basically trying to answer the question: what is Z in exp(X)exp(Y)=exp(Z).    Z is expressed as a formula involving [X,Y], [X,[X,Y]], [Y,[X,Y]], etc.  But the article doesn't seem to explain that notation.

What is [X,Y], and what is a commuter?

Comment: It is just the Lie bracket for $X,Y $ belonging to a Lie algebra, $[X,Y]:=XY-YX$ . Note that if $X,Y$ commute then $Z=X+Y$ simply! So for the general non-abelian case, BCH formula captures the behaviour of the exponential map "near the origin", by writing out $Z$ in terms of the iterative Lie brackets.

Comment: I would be useful if the wikipedia article mentioned that.    I don't have to be a Lie algebra expert to understand XY-YX for a non-commutative group (Lie or otherwise).

Comment: You don't have to be an expert on Lie algebras to have encountered the *definition* of a Lie algebra, which has $[\cdot,\cdot]$ built right in. Out of curiosity, what brings you to the BCH formula if you hadn't heard of Lie algebras beforehand?

Comment: What brings me to BCH?   It is quite innocent actually.  I'm trying to write some property based tests for a matrix manipulation library in a programming language.   The library is able to compute exp(M).   I wanted to verify that exp(X)*exp(Y) = exp(X+Y) and found it was failing.  I thought this was a bug in my exp computation.  Turns out that the relation is not true in general.    Looking into additional conditions which make it true, lead me to BCH.

Comment: And if ab = ba, then it also seems to also work for tan(a+b)=(tan a + tan b)/(1 - tan x tan y), cos(a+b)=cos(x)cos(y) - sin(x)sin(y), and sin(a+b)=sin(x)cos(y)+cos(x)sin(y).   But not in general.

Answer (score 2):

The context is this: you have a Lie group $G$, its Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ and the exponential map $\exp\colon\mathfrak g\longrightarrow G$. Since $\mathfrak g$ is a Lie algebra, there is a binary operation in it$$\begin{array}{ccc}\mathfrak g\times\mathfrak g&\longrightarrow&\mathfrak g\\(X,Y)&\mapsto&[X,Y];\end{array}$$if $\mathfrak g$ is the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{gl}(n,\Bbb R)$ of all $n\times n$ real matrices, then $[X,Y]$ is just $XY-YX$.

The Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff formula says then that, given $X,Y\in\mathfrak g$, if a certain series$$X+Y+\frac12[X,Y]+\frac1{12}\bigl[X,[X,Y]\bigr]-\frac1{12}\bigl[Y,[X,Y]\bigr]+\cdots$$converges and if $Z$ is its sum, then $e^Z=e^Xe^Y$.